# Flyout c# using mahapps

Tags: c#, mahapps.metro, flyout

Hello I am currently using library Mahapps but I have some problems. How can I pop out the flyout when clicking the "Menu 1" MenuItem? I tried with the following code but it did not work.

```
<ListBox.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem x:Name="FlyoutOverview" Header="Menu 1" IsCheckable="True" Click="flyoutOverview">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <iconPacks:PackIconModern Kind="GlobeWire"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem Header="Menu 2"/>
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem Header="Menu 3">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <iconPacks:PackIconModern Kind="People"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Menu 4">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <iconPacks:PackIconModern Kind="UserDelete"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Menu 5">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <iconPacks:PackIconModern Kind="ControlResume"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListBox.ContextMenu>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: What is your code behind for the Click event of "Menu 1" item?

Comment: sorry i new on c#.. i dont know the code

Comment: Then where do you implement this **Click="flyoutOverview"** ?

Comment: where can i find the tutorial.. i have try all at stackflow

Comment: *       private void flyoutOverview(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)<br/>
        {<br/>
<br/>
        }<br/>
*
this is the code.. but i dont know much in binding code..

Comment: Read these tutorials carefully then you will know how to implement:
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvvm/ : this is for the MVVM binding
- https://mahapps.com/controls/flyouts.html: this is how the MahApps Flyout works
There is no better way of learning than practicing the code yourself. Hope that it helps!

Comment: So it have related with binding right?

Comment: Are this related with data binding??

Comment: Yes they are. Have you tried to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have followed the tutorial links I provided then I suppose you are able to create a simple View and its ViewModel.

The View can be a Window and has its Grid content like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Controls:FlyoutsControl Grid.Column="1">
        <Controls:Flyout x:Name="yourMahAppFlyout" Header="Flyout" Background="AliceBlue" Position="Right" Width="350" 
                         IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=FlyoutOverview, Path=IsChecked}">
            <TextBlock Text="My Flyout is here" />
        </Controls:Flyout>
    </Controls:FlyoutsControl>

    <ListBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding NameList}">
        <ListBox.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem x:Name="FlyoutOverview" Header="Menu 1" IsCheckable="True" 
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsMenuItem1Checked}">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <iconPacks:PackIconModern Kind="GlobeWire"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>

                </MenuItem>
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem Header="Menu 2"/>
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem Header="Menu 3">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <iconPacks:PackIconModern Kind="People"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Menu 4">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <iconPacks:PackIconModern Kind="UserDelete"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Menu 5">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <iconPacks:PackIconModern Kind="ControlResume"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListBox.ContextMenu>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

The ViewModel can have these properties:

```
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        NameList = new ObservableCollection<string>()
        {
            "John", "Micheal", "Jack"
        };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> NameList { get; set; }

    public bool IsMenuItem1Checked
    {
        get { return _isMenuItem1Checked; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _isMenuItem1Checked, value); }
    }
```

The first menu item in the listbox binds its "IsChecked" property to "IsMenuItem1Checked" in ViewModel, and FlyOut "IsOpen" property binds to "IsChecked" of that menu item.

Comment: If i change **IsChecked="{Binding IsMenuItem1Checked}"** to **IsChecked="{Binding IsMenuItemOverview}"** but why i getting error?

Comment: @YJK what is your _IsMenuItemOverview_ ?

Comment: i dont put any variable for _IsMenuItemOverview_ yet

Comment: Then it is clear why you got the error. You need to create the Viewmodel property and then make the binding correctly. The tutorial links I provided before explain it in details

Comment: I notices that you only use view and view model...  the model?

If i want to use view and view model on my project can i do so?

Comment: @YJK Yes, you can.

Comment: So it mean the important part is View and Viewmodel.. BTW do you have skype?

Comment: @YJK No I don't use Skype. If you have any further questions then you're welcome to create another question in SOF

Comment: I have some question... If i dont want to use model... and i want to use only view and viewmodel... it is okey?